# How to pass parameter with post method in page 1 to page 2's get method's iframe

Tags: html, asp-classic

the goal is to pass value to candidatelogin2.asp's iframe from candidatelogin.asp

```
in candidatelogin.asp

<form  method="POST" action="http://127.0.0.1/hello/candidatelogin2.asp">
can only get hidden textbox value, but can not get visible textbox value in candidatelogin2.asp

<form  method="GET" action="http://127.0.0.1/hello/candidatelogin2.asp">

in candidatelogin2.asp

<form action="http://127.0.0.1/hello/login/Default.aspx?loginTypeValue='CANDIDATE'&loginemail=<

%=request.querystring("loginemail")%>&password=<%=request.querystring("password") %>" method="get" 

target="my_iframe">

<iframe src="http://127.0.0.1/hello/login/Default.aspx?loginTypeValue='CANDIDATE'&loginemail=<

%=request.querystring("loginemail")%>&password=<%=request.querystring("password") %>" width="600" 

height="400"></iframe>
```

Comment: I can not believe it! You pass the user name and the password on the query string.

Comment: it's my boss requirement. And it is not in url bar, it is in iframe, will it be captured?

Comment: Yes is the same thing - it did not matter if its in iframe, its on the url. Capture from anyone. Fire your boss, don't know anything about.

Comment: he know it too, we are only doing part of whole web, something we can not control

Answer (score 0):

While I completely agree with all others -- it is a bad idea to pass user name and password in query string -- I did at least want to show you it is easy to accomplish.

**Page1.asp**

```
<form  method="GET" action="page2.asp">
Email: <input type=text name=loginemail> <br />
Password: <input type=password name=password> <br />
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

**Page2.asp**

```
<iframe src="page3.asp?loginemail=<%=request("loginemail")%>&password=<%=request("password")%>">
<iframe>
```

**Page3.asp**

```
Contents of IFrame: <br />

<%
response.write request("loginemail")
response.write request("password")
%>
```

At minimum however, you should change GET to POST in your Form's method to keep these variables out of the query string.

Good luck.